# Git creates a new branch despite commit... How to fix this?

Tags: git, github, branch, commit

First I'll start with my workflow:

1. Created change in my local repository ( using Notepad++ )
2. Try to push changes to the remote repository - standard Git flow:

**2.1. `git add README.md`**

**2.2. `git commit --m "xxx"`**

**2.3. `git push`**

After that Git created on my GitHub new branch "master" and I need to create a pull request and after that, I can merge changes...

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 32, done.
Counting objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32/32), 6.42 KiB | 2.14 MiB/s, done.
Total 32 (delta 8), reused 22 (delta 5), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), done.
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'master' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/Mikma03/Python_Bill_Lubanovic_BookCodes/pull/new/master
remote:
To https://github.com/Mikma03/Python_Bill_Lubanovic_BookCodes.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

I strongly believe that there is a way to fix this. Do you have any suggestions?

I expect to see just a new commit on my GitHub repository without need to merge.

Comment: did you try git push -u origin main command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've been calling your local branch `master` for some time now.

You ran `git push`, which—because you're calling your local branch `master`—meant `git push origin master:master`.  That is, you had your Git send your new commit, which you made *on* your `master`, to the other Git repository over on GitHub in `https://github.com/Mikma03/Python_Bill_Lubanovic_BookCodes.git`, and then ask them (GitHub) to create or update, in their repository, a branch named `master`.

If you wish to use some other branch name on your end, *rename your branch*:

```
git branch -m new-branch-name
```

for instance.  (The `-m` option stands for *move*, which is a funny way to spell `rename`: this dates back to the Linux `mv` command for renaming files, which in turn dates back to the Unix `mv` command.)

If you wish to use the name `master` on *your* end, but the name `roxible` on GitHub, use:

```
git push origin master:roxible
```

(in general this is a bad idea as humans find this kind of name-mapping confusing, plus you have to keep repeating the colon syntax every time, which is annoying—there are some workarounds for *that* but that gets pretty far afield).

Note that when you create a new, totally-empty repository on your own computer:

```
mkdir new-repo
cd new-repo
git init
```

for instance (on a Linux system), your Git repository has no branch names in it, and yet you're *on* your `master` branch.  You're just on a branch that *does not exist*.  You have two options at this point: rename the branch that doesn't exist, with, e.g.:

```
git checkout --orphan main
```

which is a *really* weird way to spell "rename a branch that doesn't exist", or go ahead and create the first commit, and then use `git branch -m` to rename `master`.

In the latest versions of Git, `git init` has a flag, `-b`, to set the branch name:

```
git init -b main
```

which creates the repository such that the branch that doesn't exist, that you're on anyway, is named `main` instead of `master`.  This avoids having to rename the branch, but requires a pretty new version of Git.  There's also a new `init.defaultBranch` configuration variable, but this one has the drawback that if your Git is too old to know this configuration variable, `git init` silently *ignores* it.  The `-b` flag has the advantage that it either works, or `git init` complains that it has no idea what `-b` means.